# SQL average ok values per group

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to get some values out from my table, however, due to the structure of the table, I am not sure if that is possible:

A sample of a table is here, I have put some spaces in the table to make it easier to read.

As you can see there are many pages, with 3rows/page and 3channels/row.
There are also devices, each device consists in 3 segments. 9 devices/page.
And finally there are results per segment from certain analysis, passed=1 or passed=0.

```
ID channel row page segment device passed
1     1     1    1     1      1       1
2     1     1    1     2      1       0
3     1     1    1     3      1       1
4     2     1    1     1      2       0
5     2     1    1     2      2       0
6     2     1    1     3      2       0
7     3     1    1     1      3       1
8     3     1    1     2      3       0
9     3     1    1     3      3       1
10    1     2    1     1      4       1
11    1     2    1     2      4       1
12    1     2    1     3      4       1
13    2     2    1     1      5       0
14    2     2    1     2      5       1
15    2     2    1     3      5       1
16    3     2    1     1      6       1
17    3     2    1     2      6       1
18    3     2    1     3      6       1
19    1     3    1     1      7       1
20    1     3    1     2      7       0
21    1     3    1     3      7       1
22    2     3    1     1      8       1
23    2     3    1     2      8       0
24    2     3    1     3      8       1
25    3     3    1     1      9       1
26    3     3    1     2      9       0
27    3     3    1     3      9       1
NEXT PAGE..................................
28    1     1    2     1      1       0
29    1     1    2     2      1       0
30    1     1    2     3      1       1
31    2     1    2     1      2       1
32    2     1    2     2      2       1
33    2     1    2     3      2       0
34    3     1    2     1      3       1
35    3     1    2     2      3       0
36    3     1    2     3      3       1
37    1     2    2     1      4       1
38    1     2    2     2      4       0
39    1     2    2     3      4       0
40    2     2    2     1      5       0
41    2     2    2     2      5       1
42    2     2    2     3      5       0
43    3     2    2     1      6       1
44    3     2    2     2      6       1
45    3     2    2     3      6       1
46    1     3    2     1      7       0
47    1     3    2     2      7       1
48    1     3    2     3      7       1
49    2     3    2     1      8       1
50    2     3    2     2      8       1
51    2     3    2     3      8       1
52    3     3    2     1      9       0
53    3     3    2     2      9       1
54    3     3    2     3      9       0
etc.......................................
```

The calculation that I am looking for is the % of passed devices (passed=1) but grouped by device, which is for me the difficult part because, each device is passed just if all segments are passed within the device.

So device=1 if seg1=1 and seg2=1 and seg3=1

An expected output would be something like:(not real data here)

```
Device    passed   
  1        27.45
  2        56.78
  3        78.9 
  4        11.23
  5        etc
  6        etc
  7        etc
  8        etc
  9        etc
```

I know that I have to use something like that, however it is not working:

```
SELECT  device, count(passed) as devicesOK
FROM myTable
WHERE passed=1
group by device
having devicesOK=3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the percentage passed, you have to divide the number that passed by the total count per device.

```
SELECT device, ROUND(SUM(passed)/COUNT(*)/100, 2) AS passed_percent
FROM myTable
GROUP BY device
HAVING SUM(passed) = 3
```

`COUNT(passed)` counts the number of non-NULL values of `passed`. Since all your values are not `NULL`, it counts them all.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I wanted to ask how do you consider the fact that a device is ok just if its 3 segments are ok at the same time

Comment: You can use `HAVING SUM(passed) = 3` to test that.

Comment: the "passed" used in "AS passed" is the same passed as the one in "HAVING..." or it refers to the the column name?

Comment: I changed it to use a different name for `AS`, to avoid confusion.